# How do I pass VLAN traffic over a bridge to KVM VM's

Tags: linux-networking, kvm-virtualization

I have a KVM host that I would like on VLAN 1 and I would like the VM's to use VLAN 2. emo1 on the host is bridged with br0 and the physical interface is connected to a trunk port on a Cisco switch. The issue is most things I have found on the web are conflicting/old or didn't work for me.

I am running Centos 7. What would be the easiest way to tag the guests with a different VLAN than the host?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

In the host interface, configure a separate interface for each VLAN.

Since the physical interface is connected to a trunk port, all VLANs should be tagged.

So, on the host, you need to configure `emo1.1` and `emo1.2` interfaces, which correspond to VLAN 1 and VLAN 2 on the physical interface.

Then you create a bridge for the VMs, and add `emo1.2` as a bridge member.

After that, you configure `emo0.1` for the host connectivity.

The `emo0` interface should be up, but it must not have any IP address configured.

You also need to make sure that the `8021q` module is loaded so that the kernel has VLAN support.

Comment: I tried this but for some reason the sub interfaces wouldn't come up. I got an error that said "No suitable device found for this connection.". The way I set it up was emo1 had no address, emo1.1 had an ip, emo.2 had no ip and was bridged with br0 which did have an ip. I think for now I'll just make it work by using a different physical NIC but it does bother my that I couldn't make it work.    Thanks again for the help, I'm sure I just did something wrong.

Comment: I forgot to mention that one needs the VLAN kernel module, `8021q` in order to have support for VLAN interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

The Archlinux wiki has a [good article on VLANs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VLAN) that will show you how to set them up for testing.

On CentOS to do this more permanently, use `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/`.

For example, `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0.1` could be:

```
VLAN=yes
DEVICE=eth0.1
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=192.168.0.1
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
```

And `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0.2` could be:

```
VLAN=yes
DEVICE=eth0.2
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=0.0.0.0
NETMASK=0.0.0.0
BRIDGE=br0
```

You then create br0, your VM bridge, `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-br0`:

```
DEVICE=br0
TYPE=Bridge
IPADDR=192.168.1.1
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
NM_CONTROLLED=no
DELAY=0
```

Assuming  you put the appropriate forwarding rules in place, all traffic from your VMs on br0 will be tagged with VLAN id 2 when it hits the switch.